# How I can customize the Ubuntu Live ISO installer using Cubic (add, remove, and upgrade packages and set language)?

Tags: 20.04, custom-installer, customizer

I would like to modify the **ubuntu 20.04** installation iso to **include** (vlc, audacious,mc,rar,unrar, spanish support,etc), **remove** (totem,rhythmbox,english support, etc)  and **upgrade** packages. Use Cubic but change the permissions of various system directories. Leading to a security risk.
For example /etc and /usr have 777
I need customize installer becouse the computers I want installer don't have network acces
I need customize installer because I live in Cuba and is very difficult access online repository from anywhere also the connections are too slow for example in this PC (256kbs).

Comment: In this question only cant change the installer. I cant include some packages(mc,rar,vlc,openssh-server,empathy, etc), remove other(totem, rhythmbox, ...) and upgrade from repository the rest.

Comment: Unsure why this was closed with link to ancient question which has answers that are dead links or not relevant to this situation.

Comment: Post an updated answer on the dupe then. Unsure why this question must be reopened for that.

Comment: Muru, because @Lazaro asked how to use Cubic. The other question asks something different.

Answer (score 5):

1. **Install Cubic**

   First, make sure you have the latest version of Cubic following the instructions at [the Cubic web page](https://launchpad.net/cubic).

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cubic-wizard/release
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install cubic
   ```
2. **Launch Cubic**

   Navigate to the Terminal page.
3. **Add the necessary repositories**

   ```
   add-apt-repository --yes main
   add-apt-repository --yes restricted
   add-apt-repository --yes universe
   add-apt-repository --yes multiverse
   ```

   Remove your existing packages.

   ```
   apt autoremove --purge totem rhythmbox
   ```

   You should probably leave the English language packages and let them automatically be removed by the installer after installation of the OS (see step 8 below).
4. **Upgrade packages**

   ```
   apt upgrade
   ```
5. **Add your new packages**

   ```
   apt install vlc audacious mc rar unrar
   ```
6. **Install your language packages**

   (You will find these are already installed in the Live ISO).

   ```
   apt install language-pack-es language-pack-es-base language-pack-gnome-es language-pack-gnome-es-base
   ```

   [image: Cubic Terminal Page]
7. **Update permissions**

   I recommend being very careful when doing this. Making files inside /etc accessible to all users may cause your system to not boot, because some files must only be readable by root.

   As an example, you can change permissions for `/etc/network` and all files or directories in it to 777:

   ```
   cd /etc/
   chmod -R u+rw,g+rw,o+rw network
   ```
8. **Tell the Ubiquity installer to not remove your language packages**

   Navigate to the Packages page.

   Click (anywhere) on the list, and begin typing the word "language" to search for packages that begin with this word.

   **Uncheck** the following four packages:

   - `language-pack-es`
   - `language-pack-es-base`
   - `language-pack-gnome-es`
   - `language-pack-gnome-es-base`

   This will ensure that the installer **does not** remove your language packages. This is not strictly necessary, since we will select your language and locale in the preseed below (step 9), but it is a good measure nevertheless.

   You will also notice that the English language packages are flagged (check-marked) to be automatically removed by the installer after installation of your customized OS (if English is not selected as your default language).

   [image]
9. **Select your default language and locale**

   Navigate to the Options page, and select the Preseed tab.

   Click on `/preseed/ubuntu.seed` in the left pane.

   Configure your locale and language by appending the following text at the end of this file. (Note that "es" = Spanish, and "CU" = Cuba).

   ```
   # Set language, country and locale.
   d-i debian-installer/language string es
   d-i debian-installer/country string CU
   d-i debian-installer/locale string es_CU.UTF-8

   # Specify additional locales to be generated.
   d-i localechooser/supported-locales multiselect es_CU.UTF-8

   # Set keyboard layout.
   d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select es

   # Set time zone and region.
   d-i time/zone string America/Havana
   d-i debian-installer/region string es_CU.UTF-8
   ```

   Optionally, if you want multiple locales generated, separate them with commas as show here:

   ```
   # Specify additional locales to be generated.
   d-i localechooser/supported-locales multiselect es_CU.UTF-8, fr_CH.UTF-8, en_US.UTF-8
   ```

   Here are some references if you are configuring different languages or locales:

   - [List of ISO 639-1 Language Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)
   - [List of ISO 3166-1 County Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#CU)
   - [List of Ubuntu Time Zones](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man3/DateTime::TimeZone::Catalog.3pm.html)

   [image]
10. **Generate your customized ISO**

    Finally, navigate to Cubic's Generate page to create your customized ISO.

    [image]

Comment: Is step #7 "Update permissions" in any way required? If we just skip it, will customized OS retain original permissions?

Comment: Step #7 is optional. This was included to answer the original question which had asked how to change certain permissions (knowing that this would be a security risk). In fact, I recommend *not* doing step #7.

Comment: Use `sudo -E apt-add-repository ppa:cubic-wizard/release` with option `-E` if you are behind a proxy.