# How do I pre-install a program on a Live CD to boot?

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, preinstallation

I would want "program.deb" to be pre-installed to a Ubuntu Live CD.

Comment: It depends upon the release of Ubuntu, upon whether you are installing Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server, and upon whether you are installing on bare metal or into a VM.

Comment: Live ISOs are by design read-only meaning they can't be altered thus preventing damage/corruption/malware being included (the checksums won't match if altered so corruption is detected).  You can re-spin an ISO (giving it a new checksum), or write the ISO to a persistent media (thus the changes/additional packages are external to the actual *squashfs* itself, but you've not provided any specifics or release details (media has been changing to make it less architecture dependent so *arm64*, *amd64*, *s390*, *ppc64el* etc all boot the same way)

Comment: @Nmath: I’m voting to close your linked question because it is about an End of Standard Support or End of Life Release. This question was written concerning 11.04. Most of the answers use outdated, obsolete, unsupported apps with broken links, such as Remastersys. None of the answers with high reputation are of any use to a user in the modern world. It may be a good history lesson but that is not what users are looking for.

Comment: I understand **Cubic** is still working with Ubuntu 20.04, Cubic makes it easy to add a few programs to an ISO file, that can be made into a CD or DVD. https://askubuntu.com/a/1291054/43926

Comment: @C.S.Cameron - That question was never specific to an end of life release, so that closure reason is not valid.  Besides, [we don't close old questions as EOL](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16132/please-dont-flag-old-questions-as-eol) if they were on-topic when the question was asked.  It doesn't help anyone to remove content that might still be helpful.  FYI, [the highest upvoted answer still works](https://askubuntu.com/a/49679/) with 122 upvotes.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi: They say Great Minds think alike, That it the same link I posted above :-)

Comment: @Nmath: My problem is when someone suggests an old duplicate question, with many answers, but does not recommend one of the answers that still works. **Thank you for doing so**. After trying unsuccessfully to link to: Ubuntu Builder, Ubuntu Customization Kit, live-magic, Remastersys, JLIVECD, Reconstructor, ISORespin, etc the OP might be a little wary of trying the most complex answer on the page.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I did not post the link. I marked it as a duplicate, and the comment was automatically posted from my account. Amen to what you said about great minds :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments above link to lots of options. If you choose to use Cubic, here are some detailed steps:

1. Install the software:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cubic-wizard/release
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install --no-install-recommends cubic
   ```
2. Create a new project:

   Launch Cubic.

   On the first page, select a new empty directory. (For example, `/home/tank/my_live_cd`).

   Click <kbd>Next</kbd>

   On the Project page, select your original ISO. (For example `ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso`).

   Default values will be automatically filled out, so just click <kbd>Next</kbd>.

   [image: Project page with default values]
3. When you get to the Terminal page, copy your deb file:

   ```
   mkdir Temp
   cd Temp
   ```

   Drag `program.deb` onto Cubic's Terminal area to copy it into your new `Temp` directory.

   [image]
4. Then, install your package from your `program.deb` file:

   ```
   apt-add-repository universe
   apt-add-repository multiverse
   apt install --no-install-recommends gdebi-core
   gdebi program.deb
   ```

   [image: Install *.deb file]

   Remove unnecessary files.

   ```
   apt autoremove --purge gdebi-core
   cd ~
   rm -rf Temp
   ```
5. Click through the next pages, accepting the defaults:

   On the Terminal page, click <kbd>Next</kbd>.

   On the Packages page, click <kbd>Next</kbd>.

   On the Options page, click <kbd>Next</kbd>.

   On the Compression page, click <kbd>Generate</kbd>.

   On the Generate page, click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

   Click the <kbd>Close</kbd> button to exit the application.

Finally, Create a bootable USB, CD, or DVD using your new Live ISO file.

Comment: Best option is to place the answer where the OP can see it, and not make it a needle in the hay stack. Thanks PJ Singh. +1